# Tree view in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have two fields:

1. Section
2. Details (which is multi-line field  )

I need to create a tree view like structure or link on the left side with section and when clicked on it show the details on the right.

Comment: can i just store hyperlink in one list which points to the details column on the other and display the details in a webpart or something ?

Comment: You can simply achieve this by using webpart connections. Let's say you already have a webpart page with the two webparts, side by side , and there is a lookup column in the Details list to the Hyperlink list, as you said in your comment. There is already a stack exchange answer for it ( http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53105/filter-one-list-depending-on-selection-in-another-list)