# Freeze first column in SharePoint List View?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, list-view, css

I am working in SP2013 , in a particular list view  we want to freeze first column on horizontal scrolling.

Please help on this if any one having idea/code/any reference URLS.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a way to freeze the first column, but have a suggestion that may be a good workaround.

If your aim is to keep information in the first column on screen, you could try using web-parts.  If you have the permissions to do so, you can edit the page and insert a new web part.

Display the same list in two web parts.  You can connect the two lists so that they are linked - [please see this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53105/filter-one-list-depending-on-selection-in-another-list/53121#53121) for more info on how to do that.

You can display different columns in the two web parts - configure two views for this purpose.

I would suggest ensuring that your first column is displayed in the upper web part - you can then filter/select an item from the first web part and the lower web part will filter to show the corresponding data.

Best of luck with it.

David